# How to add annotation in scanned image pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations

Below is my Pdf with scanned image.I want add color when I read record from it.
After completion of reading record color need to be removed,and color added to next record using C#.
I don't have knowledge about annotation.

Comment: Where is your pdf below ?

Comment: Which PDF library do you (intend to) use?